# Spivak Calculus Chapter 1 Problem 5 (ii)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

Prove : If $a < b$ then $-b < -a$

My proof :

$a + (-b) < b + (-b) $

$a - b < 0$

$a - b + (-a) < 0 + (-a)$

$a + (-a) -b < -a$

$-b < -a$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: well yea it's totally correct

Answer (score 1):

Direct alternative proof.
$a < b $
$-a + a - b < -a + b - b  $
$-b < -a$

Comment: you have 14.5k points but I'll link it anyway? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference